# Why is the value 0 for the Max_data_length of my tables in my database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

We are using a commercial version 5.6.16 of MySQL database which seems to have a 4GB limit. We have hit 3.96GB and are experiencing performance issues with the database. We came across some documentation that says you can increase the database size by increasing the max data length. Anyway when I use the call

```
mysql> show table status like 'weather' \G
```

in CMD to find my tables size limit. I see that the Max_data_length is 0 and not 4294967295 which is the typical size of the database. So why is my Max_data_length 0?

Comment: The version we use is a 32-bit version

Comment: That's your problem then. Move to a 64-bit OS and you are good.

Comment: Sorry can you explain in more detail why that would be an issue.

Comment: @taseakpobome 2^32 = 4294967296 = 4Gb

Comment: I added an answer. You havn't told us yet what the operating system is.

Comment: What ENGINE?  MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Table size limits are affected by the OS and the file system.

From MySQL (5.6) documentation, [Limits on Table Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html):

> The effective **maximum table size** for MySQL databases **is usually determined** **by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.** The following table lists some examples of operating system file-size limits. This is only a rough guide and is not intended to be definitive. For the most up-to-date information, **be sure to check the documentation specific to your operating system.**

```
Operating System                      File-size Limit
-------------------------------------------------------------
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32                    2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS                         2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit                2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+  (using ext3 file system)  4TB
Solaris 9/10                          16TB
OS X w/ HFS+                          2TB
```

So there the problem lies.

Solution:

- Take a backup.
- Get another machine / VM with a 64-bit OS.
- Install MySQL.
- Restore your database there.
- Profit ;)

Comment: The operating system is Win32 w/ NTFS

Comment: Then you shouldn't have a problem, according to that link. Did you get "table full" errors? Are your tables MyISAM or InnoDB? What is the value of `myisam_data_pointer_size`?

Comment: And when you say Win32, what do you mean, what is the OS version exactly?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard/NTFS  64-bit

Comment: Basically we dont get any database errors. Rather when we try to insert a list of values. Some fail to insert. So when we run our application connected to this database some values are missing in the application.

Comment: hard drive has 79.8GB  but only has 28.6GB free space available

Comment: What does `show variables like 'version%';` show?

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

For `ENGINE` InnoDB, `Max_data_length` shows as 0.  The limit for such is 64TB, *regardless* of the Operating system.  (There are things that you need to do if you have an antique OS that has one of those 2GB filesystem limits.)

Do you have any other evidence that you have hit a limit?